# Float modulo operator that includes the upper value

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, if-statement, glsles

I need an efficient glsl code that doesn't have `if-else` statement.
Currently the  algorithm is like this :

```
lowp float a;
if (a > 1.0) 
   a -= 1.0;
else if (a < 0.0) 
   a += 1.0;
```

It's similar with a floating point modulo operator :

```
a = mod(a,1.0);
```

only `if a == 1`, it should `return 1`, instead of `0`.

How to do this without `if-else` though?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a mathematic representation that might do what you need - without using branching statements

For inputs between [-1, 2.0]

```
a = a + 1 - max(trunc(a), ceil(a))

Input   Output
0.3     0.3
-0.3    0.7
0.7     0.7
1.3     0.3
1.7     0.7
1       1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
value = (expression) ? (if true) : (if false);
```

example :

```
BOOL result = value ? YES : NO;
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I can't add a ternary operation because it's basically the same with if-else. And if-else is not efficient in glsl.

Comment: ok than you try #define
You may also go to through this link..
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13577/bad-practice-to-have-long-if-else-statements

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand how your code relates to the floating point modulo operator that you mention.  Such an operator converts floats to integers; your code does not.

If such a conversion is desired, use function `modff` from the standard library.

```
#include <math.h>
float a, dummy;
...
a = modff(a, &dummy);
```

If you don't want any such conversion, the answer of @devnull is a correct rewrite of your code.  If in addition you want to "include the upper value" and, e.g. have 1 map to 1, then you're in a bit of trouble, as this would involve checking whether a floating point number is integer or not.  To do this portably, I'd suggest again the use of `modff`.

**SYNOPSIS**

```
float modff(float x, float *iptr);
```

Link with `-lm`.

**DESCRIPTION**

The  `modf()`  function breaks the argument `x` into an integral part and a
fractional part, each of which has the same sign as  `x`.   The  integral
part is stored in the location pointed to by `iptr`.

Comment: Thanks for giving me a hint to the solution.